# Approve row through a form - getting blank page

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I want to show a list of all entries where the column "approved" is "no" and then place a button next to it that when clicked will change the "approved" to a "yes". I ran this through code checker and fixed a few issues with brackets and such. It now tells me there are no errors so something else is just not working with this. It is probably something small that I am missing (I hope). Can anyone help me find/understand what part of this is incorrect... and/or if there is a better way to achieve what I'm wanting?

```
<?php
  //select the database to write to
  $unapprovedsires = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nominatedsires WHERE approved = 'no'");
    //While loop to cycle through the rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($unapprovedsires)){
        $sirename = $row['sirename'];
        echo $sirename;}
?>
<ul class="admin-fields">
<?php
    foreach($row as $field){
        if(empty($field)){
            echo "....";
        }
        print '<li>' .$field.' </li>';
    }//End For Each Loop
    //print $sirename;
?>
        </ul>
<p>
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['approve'])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE nominatedsires SET approved = 'yes' WHERE sirename = '.$sirename.'") or die ("Something went wrong");
}
  ?>
    <ul>
        <li>

<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="sirename" value="$sirename" />
    <button name="approve" id="approve" type="submit">Approve Sire</button>
</form>
           </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: You need to wrap `$sirename` in PHP tags: `<input type="hidden" name="sirename" value="<?php echo $sirename; ?>" />`

Comment: Why the dots in the update query? `WHERE sirename = '.$sirename.'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned as a comment, you need to wrap `$sirename` in PHP tags with an echo statement. You are also not passing `$_POST['sirename']` into your script. It otherwise defaults to the original `$sirename` from your `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

**Warning**: the way you have your script set up, you're vulnerable to injection attacks. This is just an example to show you how to pass in variables. See: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
<?php
  //select the database to write to
  $unapprovedsires = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nominatedsires WHERE approved = 'no'");
    //While loop to cycle through the rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($unapprovedsires)){
        $sirename = $row['sirename'];
        echo $sirename;}
?>
<ul class="admin-fields">
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($unapprovedsires)){
        if(empty($row['sirename']))
            echo "....";
        else
            print '<li>' .$row['sirename'].' </li>';
    }
    //print $sirename;
?>
        </ul>
<p>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['approve'])){
        $sirename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sirename']);
        mysql_query("UPDATE nominatedsires SET approved = 'yes' WHERE sirename = '$sirename'") or die ("Something went wrong");
    }
?>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <form method="post" method="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="sirename" value="<?php echo $sirename; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="approve" id="approve" value="Approve Sire" />
            </form>
       </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I found the code on StackOverflow while searching how the heck I do what I'm attempting to do. All the dots and such were already there so I didn't change them. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Okay I put what you shared above Josh but when I click approve nothing happens... and it doesn't list each option, it just lists all the names and gives one approve button. I'm going to keep playing around with it though.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `foreach()` loop. `$row` is holding an associative array from this query: `SELECT * FROM nominatedsires WHERE approved = 'no'`, and so you should use a `while()` loop for that. I fixed your HTML form so it should submit, see edit.